# How to send a Javacript variable to an ASP.NET controller using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

So I have created a method on another page of my web app that uses $.Ajax in the Javascript section of my page to retrieve data being returned from a function in my ASP.NET controller for that page/view, and now I am trying to create a new section that will take a parameter being given to the ASP.NET controller from the Javascript script and it will return some data based on the parameter being given.

Here is my Ajax query so far:

```
function testFunction(){
    let selectedDateJS = getSelectedDate()
    let customGraphData = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomGraphData", "Graph")',

        success: console.log("success: "+success),
    })
}
```

And then here is my controller function in ASP.NET:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCustomGraphData(string selectedDate)
{
    DateTime selectedDateDT = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedDate);
    // if selectedDate is NOT a working day:
    if (!bh.IsWorkingDay(selectedDateDT)){
        // Do something if the date being selected on the form IS NOT a working day.
        return Json(null);
    }
    else// else, if it IS a working day :
    {
        CustomGraphVM selectedDatedata = await GetCustomData(selectedDateDT);
        return Json(selectedDatedata);
    }

}
```

I tried using a `data: 'myDate',` addition to the Ajax query under the `url` part but it didn't send anything (null was returned on the `string selectedDate` parameter of my ASP.NET controller function, but it was returned as null.

Also if it makes it easier, I am parsing a date to the controller from Ajax, and the date is in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

The reason why I am doing this in $.Ajax and with Javascript as opposed to doing it with the ASP.NET is because I am trying to make a dynamic update on the view - and this worked great previously with my GET request that just returned a fixed value from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `data` via AJAX then you want to match the name you gave your parameter.

```
function testFunction(){
    
    let selectedDateJS = getSelectedDate();    
    let customGraphData = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomGraphData", "Graph")',
        data: {
           selectedDate: selectedDateJs
        }
        success: console.log("success: "+success),
    });
}
```